# PHP sessions and previous dir

Tags: php, session

I have catalog named `"scripts"(PATH: /home/olo/www/site/scripts`). In this catalog i have file called `"login.php`". This file create SESSION after user login. I have file called `"index.php"(PATH: /home/olo/www/site)`. My SESSIONS created in "scripts" don't work in `"index.php"`. It showed me, that SESSION isn't set. Can anybody help me ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you execute session_start on all files that require a session? Should the session be cross-domain?

Answer (score 1):

You must start session in every page after login

try to add this code at the top of your `index.php` file

```
<?php
     session_start();
?>
```

Comment: I have it on each of my pages.

Comment: Please show the relevant sections of those pages (well formatted, the lines above are hard to read due to the lack of linebreaks)

Comment: Where does your session expire?

Answer (score 0):

Your session isn't restored. You'll have to call `session_start()`

See: [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.